# I want to connect Glazed Lists to my JTable with filled SQL table values?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, glazedlists

I'm looking for some gook looking GUI with sorting feature of JTable.Through searching I come know about Glazed List.
But here Tutorials is quite difficult.
https://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/documentation/tutorial

Can any you please guide me how can I link my Jtable to Glazed list table to view my SQL Table values via JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this Glazed Lists example is very usefull [SortedListExample.java (An example class that create a table with order and filter features)](http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/screencasts/sortedlist/SortedListExample.java)

It´s a little point to start.

Do you know that JTable can easy Sort and Filter data? 
[Sorting and Filtering (Official Oracle Documentation Swing Tutorial- JTable- Sort And Filter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think it´s better now. :)

Comment: FYI those are the guidelines given in SO. I just quoted.